# Cordova 5.3.3 and installed Cordova iOS 3.9.1 cannot accesses internet in iOS9

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ios9, cordova-plugins

I have installed below plugins,

```
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 1.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
```

In config.xml I have below link,

```
 <access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the Cordova Content Security Policy and iOS 9 App Transport Security please see my answer at [Issues with ajax request (Cordova)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106444/issues-with-ajax-request-cordova/33109870#33109870)